# ERROR: Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn

```
clf = svm.SVC()
# Giving test data as input
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.joblib')

GCP_PROJECT = 'career-banao-project'
BUCKET_NAME="career_banao_bucket"
MODEL_BUCKET = 'gs://career_banao_bucket'
VERSION_NAME = 'v1'
MODEL_NAME = 'career_banao_model'

!gsutil mb $MODEL_BUCKET

!gsutil cp ./model.joblib $MODEL_BUCKET

!gcloud ai-platform models create $MODEL_NAME

!gcloud ai-platform versions create $VERSION_NAME \
--model=$MODEL_NAME \
--framework='scikit-learn' \
--runtime-version=1.15 \
--origin=$MODEL_BUCKET \
--python-version=3.7 \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT
```

Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error: "Failed to load model: Could not load the model: /tmp/model/0001/model.joblib. No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'. (Error code: 0)" Plz Help...

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer that might resolve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I also got the same issue, but I found, I am exporting the model with different version and the version runtime-version=1.15 is providing is different one.
So from https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list check your desire version and install it by defining explicitly, issue will gone.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow community! First of all, questions should always start with a context (explain what and where you are trying to do it) and then you can include your procedure or code and particular error / logs. This would help a lot troubleshooting your issue.

As for your error, [runtime](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list) 1.15 uses scikit-learn 0.20, whereas module "[_classes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/_classes.py)" is found in 0.22 (in 0.20 it is called "[classes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/svm/classes.py)" (no underscore)).

Try using runtime version 2.1 in order to fix your issue.

Comment: Now I got,
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Selected framework (SCIKIT_LEARN) is not available for runtime version 2.1.